# Select specefic rows from a 2d Numpy array using a sparse binary 1-d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am having a issues  figuring out to do this operation

So I have and the variable `index` 1xM sparse binary array and I have a 2-d array (NxM)  `samples`. I want to use  `index` to select specific rows of `samples` adnd get  a 2-d array.

I have tried stuff like:

```
idx = index.todense()  == 1
samples[idx.T,:]
```

but nothing.

So far I have made it work doing this:

```
idx = test_x.todense() == 1 
selected_samples = samples[np.array(idx.flat)]
```

But there should be a cleaner way.

To give an idea using a fraction of the data:

```
print(idx.shape) #  (1, 22360)
print(samples.shape) (22360, 200)
```

Comment: If samples is really high dimensional and dense, how is treating index as being either sparse or not significant at all?

Comment: index is sparse because is only says which rows should we picked from samples so from all the 22360 we only want 10, then it makes sense.

Comment: yeah, it makes sense; but it isn't significant. I don't quite get what your problem is though; the sample code you post seems like it should be working. But if you think it matters; all sparse matrices store their indices internally in some way or another, which you can access directly without the conversion to a dense matrix

Comment: It does not work... but I found the cause... idx or index should be made flat for some reason. It works when I do something like  samples[np.array(idx.flat)]

Comment: funny; I tested that because I thought it might be your problem; but it works in numpy 1.8

Comment: I am testing that in 1.7.1 that might be the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer:

```
selected_samples = samples[index.nonzero()[1]]
```

The long answer:

The first problem is that your index matrix is 1xN while your sample ndarray is NxM. (See the mismatch?) This is why you needed to call `.flat`.

That's not a big deal, though, because we just need the nonzero entries in the sparse vector. Get those with `index.nonzero()`, which returns a tuple of (row indices, column indices). We only care about the column indices, so we use `index.nonzero()[1]` to get those by themselves.

Then, simply index with the array of nonzero column indices and you're done.

Comment: Actually it does not work in my version of Numpy! I get (1, 219, 200) as the resulting shape.

Comment: If you call `.squeeze()` on the result, do you get what you expect?